# How to use console-made resources in AWS for your expo router project

Tags: amazon-web-services, expo, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have created a user pool in Cognito using the console. Apparently there are two ways to connect into these resources, the first one is thru Amplify and SDK. Since I've read tons of good review for Amplify that's where I decided to go in.

Upon reading the documentation/watching tutorials I've seen people being able to connect their app into aws through amplify-created resources. But what if these resources were created in the console? How do I do it?

In the future, these resources would most likely be created by IaC tools like terraform. Given these, is it still a good idea to use Amplify or should I just stick with SDK provided for each service?